# bar plot with 24 hours in the x-axis with date time data of only the beginning of this section

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime, bar-chart

I want to draw a bar plot (or histgram but not other plot) such that x value corresponds to the time period but the x-axis label is from 00:00 to 23:59 with half-an-hour interval.

The problem is in my dataframe: the value in column ["Start Time"] is of type "datetime.time" looks like

```
0    00:30:00

1    06:00:00

2    07:00:00

3    09:10:00

4    15:30:00

5    18:00:00

6    19:00:00
```

['Main Street Green (s)'] is the corresponding value. eg:

```
0     NaN

1    13.5

2    25.5

3    50.5

4    55.5

5    20.5

6    38.5
```

I want the height of bar from 00:00 to 00:30 to be 0
the height of bar from 00:30 to 06:00 to be 13.5
the height of bar from 06:30 to 07:00 to be 25.5
...

I have seen a lot line plot. 
https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/61484/matplotlib.dates.HourLocator
is the most valuable resource I have ever found

```py
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8.0, 6.0)
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(Dayton_weekday["Start Time"], Dayton_weekday['Main Street Green (s)'], color = 'blue', label="main street")
#set ticks every half an hour
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(0,24,48))) 
#set major ticks format
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
ax.set_xlim(["00:00", "23:59"])
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
```

In my code I use ax.plot
that is because if I use ax.bar
"ValueError: microsecond must be in 0..999999" will be returned
so I do not know how to draw a bar plot using the data I have

Comment: `ax.plot.bar(Dayton_weekday['Start Time'], Daton_weekday['Main...']`?

Comment: that does not work. will return error "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'bar'”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach that should give you what you're looking for.

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

Manually create the times we want to plot. In your dataset the time listed is corresponding with the end of the previous bar. To accommodate instances where a bar passes over midnight, it may be easier for the time to correspond with the start of the bar. In the code below I've modified your original dataset to use this approach. The first time in the list will be the first time listed on the x-axis of the plot.

```
times = [dt.time(0,30,0),
         dt.time(6,0,0),
         dt.time(7,0,0),
         dt.time(9,10,0),
         dt.time(15,30,0),
         dt.time(18,0,0),
         dt.time(19,0,0)]
```

Rather than plotting the `dt.time()` on the x-axis, it could be easier to plot the number of seconds that have elapsed in the day. Below we use a list comprehension to convert the `times` into the number of seconds elapsed.

```
seconds = [(x.hour * 3600 + x.minute * 60 + x.second)
           for x in times]
```

Note: I removed the `NaN` at the beginning of `values` and added a fictional `5.5` to the end so that the example of a bar going from 19:00 to 0:30 could be shown.

```
# manually add the y-axis values
values = [13.5,
          25.5,
          50.5,
          55.5,
          20.5,
          38.5,
          5.5]
```

Now we create two lists that will be used to specify where on the x-axis the ticks should be placed, and what label to assign to each of those ticks. If the number of seconds elapsed is divisible by 1800 (30 minutes), that number will be used as one of the ticks. `start_time` will be the number of seconds elapsed for the first item in `times`. This is where the x-axis will begin.

```
start_time = (times[0].hour * 3600 + times[0].minute * 60 + times[0].second)
xticks = [x + start_time for x in range(60 * 60 * 24) if x % 1800 == 0]
```

In order to display the time rather than the number of seconds elapsed, we must use `dt.timedelta()` to convert the integer to a `dt.time`. If the `start_time` is a value greater than `0`, then there will be `xticks` with values of at least `86400`. We must subtract `86400` from these values to prevent the `xticklabels` from appearing as `one day, 0:30`.

```
def label_format(seconds):
    if seconds >= 86400:
        seconds -= 86400

    return str(dt.timedelta(seconds=seconds))

xticklabels = [label_format(x) for x in xticks]
```

Now we can create the plot. Since we're creating a histogram style chart with unequal bar widths, we need a way to specify the bar width. `bar_traits()` can be used to determine the starting point and width of the bar based on the starting point of the x-axis and the starting point of the next bar.

```
def bar_traits(ix, second, seconds, start_time):
    if ix < len(seconds) - 1:
        if seconds[ix + 1] < second:
            width = 86400 + seconds[ix + 1] - second
        else:
            width = seconds[ix + 1] - second
    else:
        if start_time < second:
            width = 86400 + start_time - second
        else:
            width = start_time - second
    if start_time > second:
        second += 86400

    return second, width
```

Code to create the plot using `bar_traits()` to handle plotting across midnight.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8))

for ix, (second, value) in enumerate(zip(seconds, values)):
    second, width = bar_traits(ix, second, seconds, start_time)
    ax.bar(second, value, width=width, align='edge', color='C0')

ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels, rotation=90)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Your answer is great and almost offers a perfect solution to my problem.

Comment: Your answer has only One little flaw. What if there should be value between 19:00 and 0:30? The height of the bar between 0:00 to 0:30 cannot be calculated because the value does not show up until the end of the pd.Series.

Comment: If you want a bar that covers 19:00 through 0:30, it may be misleading to have the axis span from 0:00 to 23:59. That approach would cause the viewer to interpret 0:00 through 0:30 and 19:00 through 23:59 as two separate segments.

One possible approach would be to have the x-axis run from 0:30 through 0:29.

Comment: @CSY I updated my response to account for instances when we want to plot bars that pass over midnight.